# The use of 部 as a classifier in Mandarin

Tags: grammar, mandarin, usage

So I’ve read that 部 is used for machines, films and literature. So does that mean I can use 部 for words like 书，词典, etc even though they usually go with 本？

Comment: 那部电影把我吓得要死。  this can also work and here 那 may be pronounced nei4 (especially in Taiwan) and it normally comes before a MW (measure word) and means those.  =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **sometimes**.

The reference to literature does not refer to physical books, but to *works* of literature. E.g.

> BBC评选21世纪最伟大的**12部小说**
>
> (The) twelve greatest 21st century **novels** chosen by the BBC

The case with 字典 and 詞典 is different, as it can refer to the "work" or to the "book".

> 中国第一部**字典**—说文解字
>
> The first **(character) dictionary** in China, the Shuowen Jiezi

Note that poetry collection 詩集 can also be used in this way, although individual poems not so.

書 wouldn't go with 部 - it doesn't refer to a *work*.

Answer (score 0):

besides the distinction between the physical book and the work, 部 also implies the massive body of content and the grandeur theme.